# Use 2 "For Each" Loops Together - Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to use 2 different arrays to put 2 different data points in 2 different fields in a word document. I can run a single "For Each" loop to get one of the fields populated, but I don't know how to run 2 "For Each" loops together to get both fields populated before saving out the document. Here is my current code:

```
Sub Numbering()
'
' Account Numbering and Naming Macro
'
'
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Dim AccountNumbers As Variant, AccountNumber As Variant
    AccountNumbers = Array("20T5555", "20T3333", "20T8888", "20T1111")

Dim AccountNames As Variant, AccountName As Variant
    AccountNames = Array("Branch 1", "Branch 2", "Branch 3", "Branch 4")

Set Rng1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AccountNumber").Range
Set Rng2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AccountName").Range

    For Each AccountNumber In AccountNumbers

    AccountNumber1 = AccountNumber
    Rng1.Delete
    Rng1.Text = AccountNumber1

            For Each AccountName In AccountNames

            AccountName1 = AccountName
            Rng2.Delete
            Rng2.Text = AccountName1

    ' Silent Save_to_PDF Macro
    '
     ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
     Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, "template.docx", Trim(AccountNumber1) & ".pdf"), _
     ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
     wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
     wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
     CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
     BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

            Next AccountName
     Next AccountNumber

ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub
```

The desired outcome would be to have 20T5555 in one field and Branch 1 in the other on the first output document, 20T3333 and Branch 2 on the second, etc.

Comment: Usually this is done with [mail merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3). But even if you don't want to use it, I don't see what your problem is because you seem to have two `for each` loops (that are nested and so produce a cartesian join of your data arrays). If you want a different type of join, use a `for` loop with the index from `lbound` to `ubound` of one of the arrays (they must be of same length then).

Comment: @GSerg I'm very new to messing with VBA. Can you post a code snippet showing how to use the loops together so that during each pass the same index number from each array gets put into the document?

Comment: @GSerg I added additional information to my post. I don't want a cartesian join, I want to join index 1 to index 1, index 2 to index 2, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/fornext-statement) loop can be used to get the items with same index:

```
AccountNumbers = Array("20T5555", "20T3333", "20T8888", "20T1111")
AccountNames = Array("Branch 1", "Branch 2", "Branch 3", "Branch 4")

For i = 0 To Ubound(AccountNames)
    Debug.Print AccountNumbers(i), AccountNames(i)
Next i
```

Comment: AH! Sweet mystery of life at last I've found you!

Thank you, thank you, thank you!